# Downloading large files to PC from OAS Server

Tags: oracle, forms, oracle10g, download

We have an Oracle 10g forms application running on a Solaris OAS server, with the forms displaying in IE.  Part of the application involves uploading and downloading files (Word docs and PDFs, mainly) from the PC to the OAS server, using Oracle's webutil utility.

The problem is with large files (anything over 25Megs or so), it takes a long time, sometimes many minutes.  Uploading seems to work, even with large files.  Downloading large files, though, will cause it to error out part way through the download.

I've been testing with a 189Meg file in our development system. Using `WEBUTIL_FILE_TRANSFER.Client_To_DB` (or `Client_To_DB_with_Progress`), the download would error out after about 24Megs.  I switched to `WEBUTIL_FILE_TRANSFER.URL_To_Client_With_Progress`, and finally got the entire file to download, but it took 22 minutes. Doing without the progress bar got it down to 18 minutes, but that's still too long.

I can display files in the browser, and my test file displayed in about 5 seconds, but many files need to be downloaded for editing and then re-uploaded.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this uploading and downloading faster?  At this point, I'm open to almost any idea, whether it uses webutil or not. Solutions that are at least somewhat native to Oracle are preferred, but I'm opn to suggestions.

Thanks,
AndyDan

Comment: Quick question, is webcache in use on the OAS?

Comment: Yes, it is. I don't know what it means, though.

Comment: There appears to be performance problems with some webutil functions (although not the one you mention) when forms is accessed via oas that is using webcache. If you have access to metalink have a look at note: 330852.1

In addition it is also worth having a look at metalink note: 443405.1 Performance Decreasing Using Web Cache in Combination With Oracle Forms

I haven't used webutil to download such large files, so I may be sending you off on a wild goose chase, but I think it is worth trying it in an environment where it isn't used.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into those notes.  I've been searching metalink, but hadn't found those yet.  We are also experiencing performance problems with forms loading, so they might help with that, too.

Comment: Well, we've disabled webcache, but haven't seen a significant difference, if any, in performance.  We're looking at other options, but those are mainly for the forms performance.  My main concern is with the file transfers.

Comment: Well, the forms performance problem turned out to be our servers.  They're multi-threaded, but forms is single-threaded.  It looks like we're going to replace all 4 of our OAS servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using CLIENT_HOST to call an FTP command to download the files.  My 189MB test file took 20-22 minutes to download using `WEBUTIL_FILE_TRANSFER.URL_To_Client_With_Progress`, and only about 20 seconds using FTP.  It's not the best solution because it leaves the FTP password exposed on the PC temporarily, but only for as long as the download takes, and even then the user would have to know where to find it.

So, we're implementing this for now, and looking for a more secure but still performant long term solution.

Answer (score 0):

This may be totally out to lunch, but since you're looking for any thoughts that might help, here are mine.

First of all, I'm assuming that the actual editing of the files happens outside the browser, and that you're just looking for a better way to get the files back and forth.

In that case, one option I've used in the past is just to route around the web application using Apache, or any other vanilla web server you like.  For downloading, create a unique file session token, remember it in the web application, and place a copy of the file, named with the token (e.g. <unique token>.doc), in a download directory visible to Apache.  Then provide a link to the file that will be served via Apache.

For upload, you have a couple of options.  One is to use the mechanism you've got, then when a file is uploaded, you just have to match on the token in the name to patch the file back into your archive.  Alternately, you could create a very simple file upload form separate from your application that will upload the file to a temp directory via Apache, then route the user back into your application and provide the token in the URL HTTP GET-style or else in a cookie.

Before you go to all that trouble, you'll want to make sure that your vanilla web server will provide better upload and download speed and reliability than your current solution, but it should.

As an aside, I don't know whether the application server you're using provides HTTP compression, but if it does, you should make sure it's enabled and working.  This is probably the best single thing you can do to increase transfer speed of large files, assuming they're fairly compressible.  If your application server doesn't support it, then most any vanilla web server will.

I hope that helps.

Comment: That amount of redesign will totally be a last resort, but thanks for the ideas.  I am looking into the HTTP compression, and making sure it's enabled.  I'll let you know.